# Showing an * next to smallest value in a table javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, min

I am trying to find the smallest value of fuel consumption in my table. I am not sure how to find it.
I have a user input the amounts for 5 vehicles. The collection point is an object that has constuctor function with 5 properties. then I have stored the details of the five objects in an array of 5 objects.
when I try to write the code for obtaining the lowest number I get my display as the first with a * and the next lowest with a * and the next lowest as a *. All values after the lowest are blank. I just want the lowest as a *. below is the code after I have had the user input 5 times. All this is within a for loop. one of the properties calculates the consumption in the original object constuctor function.

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
  registrationPlateNumber = prompt("Please enter a 6 character registration number.", "");
  while (String(registrationPlateNumber).length != 6) {
    registrationPlateNumber = prompt("Invalid registration number! Please enter a 6 character registration number.", "");
  }

  fuelTankVolume = prompt("Please enter the volume of the vehicle's fuel tank in litres.", "");
  fuelTankVolume = parseInt(fuelTankVolume);
  while (isNaN(fuelTankVolume) || fuelTankVolume <= 0) {
    fuelTankVolume = prompt("Invalid volume! Please enter the volume of the vehicle's fuel tank in litres.", "");
    fuelTankVolume = parseInt(fuelTankVolume);
  }

  distanceTravelled = prompt("Please enter the distance the vehicle can travel on a full tank of fuel.", "");
  distanceTravelled = parseInt(distanceTravelled);
  while (isNaN(distanceTravelled) || distanceTravelled <= 0) {
    distanceTravelled = prompt("Invalid distance! Please enter the distance the vehicle can travel on a full tank of fuel.", "");
    distanceTravelled = parseInt(distanceTravelled);
  }

  VehicleArray[x] = new Vehicle(registrationPlateNumber, fuelTankVolume, distanceTravelled);

  document.writeln("<tr>");
  document.writeln("<td>" + VehicleArray[x].registrationPlateNumber + "</td>");
  document.writeln("<td>" + VehicleArray[x].fuelTankVolume + "</td>");
  document.writeln("<td>" + VehicleArray[x].distanceTravelled + "</td>");
  document.writeln("<td>" + VehicleArray[x].fuelConsumption + "</td>");

  if (VehicleArray[x].fuelConsumption < LowestConsumption) {
    LowestConsumption = VehicleArray[x].fuelConsumption;
    MostEfficient = LowestConsumption;
    MostEfficient = x;
  }

  if (x == MostEfficient) {
    document.writeln("<td>*</td>");
  }
  else if (x != MostEfficient) {
    document.writeln("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach, each time you add an element to the `VehicleArray`, you are checking if this element is the minimum compared to the previously added ones, and if it is, you are marking it directly with an asterisk.

**However, there could be elements that have not been added yet that have smaller values.** But as the for loop did not reach these yet, the current element is *marked with an asterisk*.

Then at the next iteration, if the next vehicle's fuel consumption is even lower, *it will also be marked with an asterisk*, and so on.

The fix for this is to **use two for loops**: one for filling the array and getting the minimum, and then another one for displaying the elements in the table.

```
 //first loop: add all elements to the array and get the index of the minimum

 var MostEfficient = 0;
 for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++){
    //code for user prompts...

    //adding the vehicle to the array
     VehicleArray[x] = new Vehicle(registrationPlateNumber, fuelTankVolume, distanceTravelled);

     //checking if it is the minimum for now; only the final minimum will be used in the next loop
     if (VehicleArray[x].fuelConsumption < LowestConsumption){
         LowestConsumption = VehicleArray[x].fuelConsumption;
          MostEfficient = x;
         }

}

//second for loop to write the elements to the document
//now MostEfficient won't update anymore, and will point to the final minimum

for(var x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
    document.writeln(  "<tr>");
    document.writeln(   "<td>" + VehicleArray[x].registrationPlateNumber + "</td>");
    document.writeln(   "<td>" + VehicleArray[x].fuelTankVolume + "</td>");
    document.writeln(   "<td>" + VehicleArray[x].distanceTravelled + "</td>");
    document.writeln(   "<td>" + VehicleArray[x].fuelConsumption + "</td>");

    if (x == MostEfficient){
         document.writeln("<td>*</td>");
    }
     else if (x != MostEfficient){
         document.writeln("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
     }
}
```

Also, on a side note, why are you doing this?

```
MostEfficient = LowestConsumption;
MostEfficient = x;
```

Wrong variable name maybe? Otherwise the first statement is useless.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the 2 loops. I thought I may have had to do that, but was not sure. Got it to work now.

Comment: @TheBear Glad this helps! If this solved your problem, consider upvoting/marking as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a single loop since you don't know the user's input before it's given.

Separating the algorithm in two loops should be better: one that fills up `VehicleArray` and one another that display the table. In between you'll need to find `MostEfficient`.

Since it seems like homework I'll not give you code as an answer but I can schematize:

```
loop:
  -> fetching data and filling the array

-> finding the most efficient

-> displaying the table
```